# FullCalendar : replace string on event title

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm trying to remove some string in the title of my events, only on month view but I didn't succeed.

```
eventRender: function(event, element, view) { // Modify month et week view.
  if (view.type == 'month' || view.type == 'agendaWeek') {
    element.find('.fc-title').html().replace('Mr.', '');
  }
}
```

I just want to see First and last name on month view.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is because although you're making the replacement, you're not doing anything with the resulting string. You need to set that back to the text value of the element.

To make this process simpler, you can provide a function to `text()`, like this:

```
element.find('.fc-title').text(function(i, t) {
  return t.replace('Mr.', '')
});
```

Comment: Nice catch:- `You need to set that back to the text value of the element.`. +1